# angular js fetching data from url

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js.I am trying to fetch data from url.I know how to fetch data from json with single array.But if the json has many arrays,then how to fetch it?

For example:
The json is as follows:

```
{
    "Details": [{
        "approved": [{
            "count": "2124",
            "type": "Approved ",
            "desc": "New registration"
        }, {
            "count": "902",
            "type": "Deemed approved ",
            "desc": "New registration"
        }, {
            "count": "60",
            "type": "Approved ",
            "desc": null
        }, {
            "count": "5",
            "type": "Deemed approved ",
            "desc": null
        }, {
            "count": "29",
            "type": "Approved ",
            "desc": null
        }]
    }, {
        "pending": [{
            "count": "492",
            "type": "Amendment of core fields"
        }, {
            "count": "18",
            "type": "New registration"
        }, {
            "count": "1",
            "type": null
        }]
    }, {
        "rejected": [{
            "count": "29",
            "type": "New registration"
        }]
    }, {
        "resubmit": [{
            "count": "9",
            "type": "New registration"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you send the request as follows:

```
$http.get('/data').then(function(response) {
    response // your JSON
});
```

Now inside response you will have your entire JSON as a javascript object. So you can use it as follows:

```
response.Details.approved[0].count // 2124
response.Details.pending[0].count // 492
```